# Obtener valor maximo de un array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Necesito obtener el valor máximo de acuerdo a esta consulta y sólo me devuelve el número 9, siendo que hay muchas más filas y el valor máximo que debería devolver es más alto.

```html
<?php
$rs = "SELECT MAX(id_sucursal_cliente) AS sucint FROM sucursales WHERE id_clienteSuc = '$id'";
if ($resultadoSin = $mysqli->query($rs)) {
while ($row = $resultadoSin->fetch_row()) {
$sucint = trim($row[0]);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Podrías usar la propiedad `max(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 80));`, eso te dará el valor mas alto de un array;

Comment: Tu consulta parece estar correcta, que valores te devuelve si le quitas la función MAX() a tu query? dentro de esos, hay algún valor mayor a 9?

Comment: Por favor, incluye valores de ejemplo en tu BD y por qué 9 no es el valor correcto

Comment: Tengo valores como 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,18.....25,28,45,48

Comment: Los valores que te devuelva van a depender de lo que tengas en la variable `$id`

Comment: La variable es correcta.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM nombreBadeDatos";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    $mayor = 0;
    while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
        if ($filas['0'] > $mayor) {
            $mayor = $filas['0'];
        }
    }
    echo "El valor mayor: ".$mayor;
```

Comment: Responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad, edita por favor y explica tu respuesta